# Field <select> in <td>, with long text, crushing the table

Tags: html, angularjs, css, sass

I have a table, in `<td>` I have some inputs and selects. And when `<option>` in `<select>` has a long text - it expands `<td>`, so it crushing the table. As usual in table td = th content length, and min width of td = length of biggest word in th. If I make width to td or th - it's not working, just width to select. But I have dynamic content in options so it will be bad to make static width for it. How can I make that select have not expands td and be equally th widh? [Plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/uhE1MKKmdPOvma3zZqZp?p=preview)

Comment: What do you mean by "crushing the table"?

Comment: If content in option will be very large - td will be the same size, so table view beyond the edge

Comment: Add `max-width` to your element's style

Comment: @SAM I guess you right, but I have a dynamic table so if I setup max-width = 100px and it will be good for 4 columns table - for 2 columns it will be bad(

Comment: Consider changing direction of your table so that it would be left-to-right instead of the current top-to-bottom, so selects would be arranged in a column instead of current row. Or drop using table and use e.g. `DL/DT/DD` instead.

Comment: If any of the posted answers solved your question, please accept it, if not, let us know that we can do to find you one that does

Comment: @LGSon yes, I know. in plnk your answer works, so it can be solution for this problem, but unfortunately in my real project it's not working, so I vote your answer

Answer (score 1):

Since table elements grow by their content you need to give them a width, so if you update your CSS like this it will work

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  width: 25%;
}
td select {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Sample snippet

```css
table th, table td {
  border:1px solid grey;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  width: 25%;
}
td select {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Group Name</th>
          <th style='width:50px'>Members</th>
          <th>Genre</th>
          <th>From</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <select>
              <option>Red Hot Chili Peppers</option>
              <option>Depeche Mode</option>
              <option>very-very-very long text, it will be crush the table</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>very-very-very long text, it will be crush the table</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select>
              <option>funk-rock/rock/alternative</option>
              <option>Synthpop/new-wave</option>
              <option>very-very-very long text, it will be crush the table</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select>
              <option>USA</option>
              <option>UK</option>
              <option>very-very-very long text, it will be crush the table</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply width to select element too:

```
<select style="width:50px;"></select>
```